# no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

i am getting this error what i am dong wrong

```
library(RJDBC)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(shinydashboard)
library(gridExtra)
library(DT)
```

ggplotly not working what i am doing wrong not able to get it

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
      if (is.null(input$sector) ){return()
      } else if(input$sector == "pick one") { return()
      } else p1 <-**ggplotly**(ggplot(data = subdata1() ,aes(x=SaleDate,y=Total))+  geom_point(stat='summary', fun.y=sum) +
          geom_line(colour = "red")+geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(Total)),colour = "blue")+ geom_text(data = subdata1(), aes(label = Total), 
                                                 position=position_jitter(width=1,height=0.8),  size=3)))+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
          labs(x = "SaleDate",
               y = "Total")
      print(p1 + theme(axis.text.x =
                         element_text(size  = 10,angle = 45,hjust = 1,vjust = 1)))

      })
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you loaded the plotly package in your library list. Try loading it?

```
 library(plotly)
```

Comment: i forgot to mention but it is there

Comment: It can be verions inconsistency :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be old thread but the answer might help someone in future. It seems like this problem might pop up randomly sometimes if you resize the windows. Here is the [github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2514) issue on the same error using ggplot.